# Why does clojure attempt to resolve this symbol?

Tags: clojure, macros

I am working through the Armstrong Numbers exercise on Exercism's Clojure track. An armstrong number is a number equal to the sum of its digits raised to the power of the number of digits. 153 is an Armstrong number, because: `153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153`. 154 is not an Armstrong number, because: `154 != 1^3 + 5^3 + 4^3 = 1 + 125 + 64 = 190`.

The test file for this exercise will call the `armstrong?` function, pass in a number, and expects true if the number is an Armstrong number. I have already solved the problem with this code:

```
(ns armstrong-numbers)

(defn pow [a b]
  (reduce * 1 (repeat b a)))

(defn armstrong? [num]
  (->> num
       (iterate #(quot % 10))
       (take-while pos?)
       (map #(mod % 10))
       ((fn [sq]
          (map #(pow % (count sq))
               sq)))
       (apply +)
       (= num)))
```

but now I am trying to refactor the code. This is what I would like the code to look like:

```
(ns armstrong-numbers
  (:require [swiss.arrows :refer :all]))

(defn pow [a b]
  (reduce * 1 (repeat b a)))

(defn armstrong? [num]
  (-<>> num
        (iterate #(quot % 10))
        (take-while pos?)
        (map #(mod % 10))
        (map #(pow % (count <>))
             <>)
        (apply +)
        (= num)))
```

A link to the package required above: https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows.

In the first code section, I create an implicit function within the thread-last macro because the sequence returned from the map form is needed in two different places in the second map form. That implicit function works just fine, but I just wanted to make the code sleeker. But when I test the second code block, I get the following error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: <> in this context`.

I get this error whether I use `#()`, `partial` , or `fn` inside the second map form. I have figured out that because all of the preceding are macros (or a special form in `fn`s case), they cannot resolve `<>` because it's only meaningful to the `-<>>` macro, which is called at a later point in macroexpansion. But why do `#()`, `partial`, and `fn` attempt to resolve that character at all? As far as I can see, they have no reason to know what the symbol is, or what it's purpose is. All they need to do is return that symbol rearranged into the proper s-expressions. So why does clojure attempt to resolve this (`<>`) symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<>` symbol is only valid in the topmost level of a clause (plus literals for set, map, vector directly therein).  `-<>` and `-<>>` do not establish bindings (as in `let`) for `<>`, but do code insertion at macro expansion time.

This code insertion is done only at toplevel, because making it work deeper is not only much more complex (you need a so-called *code walker*), but also raises *interesting* questions regarding the nesting of arrow forms.  This complexity is likely not worth it, for such a simple effect.

If you want a real binding, you can use `as->` (from `clojure.core`).

Comment: FWIW it's not difficult and you don't need a code walker. Just insert a let-binding instead of trying to do the replacement yourself: the compiler is quite good at them. This is what as-> does.

Comment: (The reason swiss-arrows finds this hard is that it wants to *also* allow you to omit the symbol, which means it needs to know whether there were any instances of it present, so it needs to do the replacement itself. Personally I think this is just bad API design, and it would be more clear if <> were required in each clause.)

Comment: @amalloy: that was what I was alluding to, but I should have made it more explicit.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. The problem isn't that clojure attempts to resolve `<>` prior to macro-expansion time, the problem is that clojure exits macro-expansion time with `<>` still present because `-<>>` can't see it outside of the top-level.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `-<>>` is quite clear that it doesn't behave the way you wish it did:

> "the 'diamond spear': top-level insertion of x in place of single
>      positional '<>' symbol within the threaded form if present, otherwise
>      mostly behave as the thread-last macro. Also works with hash literals
>      and vectors."

It performs replacement:

- Of a single symbol
- At the top level of the threaded form

Your example wishing to use it for multiple symbols, nested within subforms, will thus not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake leaving off the `<>` symbol in most of your forms in the failing case.  Here is a working version (using the similar `it->` macro in place of the Swiss Arrows). I also cleaned up the `pow` a bit.

```
(defn pow-int [a b] (Math/round (Math/pow a b)))

(defn armstrong? [num]
  (it-> num
        (iterate #(quot % 10) it)
        (take-while pos? it)
        (map #(mod % 10) it)
        (map #(pow-int % (count it)) it)
        (apply + it)
        (= it num)))

(armstrong? 153) => true
(armstrong? 154) => false
```

You can [find the docs on `it->` here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro).

---

If you leave off the (collection) arg to a function like `map`, it returns a transducer; [from the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/core-library):

```
(map f)(map f coll)(map f c1 c2)(map f c1 c2 c3)(map f c1 c2 c3 & colls)

Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to
the set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the
set of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
f should accept number-of-colls arguments. Returns a transducer when
no collection is provided.
```

And, [always refer to the Clojure CheatSheet!](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

Comment: Thank you for referring me to `it->`. Using that works and gets the code to be as sleek as I wanted. But I don't think the `<>` symbol is necessary. The swiss arrows docs say that `-<>>` defaults to `->>` behavior if `<>` is absent. I am still curious though why the implicit function form can resolve `it` but couldn't resolve `<>`.